# Можно ли для Android сделать игру-раннер с фоном из видеоряда?

Tags: android, разработка-игр, графика

Я хотела бы разложить видеоряд на отдельные кадры, и далее использовать их как фон для игры. И в связи с этим возникло сразу два связанных вопроса:

1. Почему в принципе в играх (по крайней мере, для Android) в качестве фона практически не используются фото, а используется рисованная графика? Такие картинки меньше весят? Но ведь можно же сжать/обработать/конвертировать в другой формат фотографии, чтобы они весили так же?
2. Если это в принципе возможно, то какие инструменты (какие движки) для создания такой игры можно использовать? Подойдёт ли libgdx для этой цели? Хотелось бы найти что-то, где знания Java будут достаточны (в крайнем случае, C++).

Comment: в чем разница между фото и рисованной графикой? используют все если нужно

Comment: вы можете использовать OpenGL ES классы и писать с 0 или взять любой движок)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно практически все. Различается лишь количество сложностей.

1. Причин к использованию рисованной графики немало:

   - Рисованную графику гораздо проще рисовать и корректировать (менять размеры, оттенки, детали и т.п.), чем фото или тем более видео;
   - Рисованная графика гораздо легче адаптируется к любому размеру экрана и соотношениям сторон, будь то SVGA или 8k+;
   - При использовании графики, ее очень легко подгонять к игре, а игру - к графике. Показалось вам, что прыжок на платформу надо сделать на 10пикс больше - подвинули графику и готово. С фото все гораздо сложнее;
   - Рисованую графику проще интегрировать с физикой - платформа прямоугольник на рисунке, и в физике, а на фото, у нее неизбежно есть огрехи, наклон и т.п.;
   - Если мы говорим об игре, в которой есть хотя бы намек на 2,5D (параллакс, глубина, передний/задний планы), то фото придется разделять на слои - весьма непростая задача, если нужен красивый результат;
   - Рисованую графику легче сделать интерактивной - достаточно отделить какой-то объект и изменить его. Фото не располагает к простому разделению на части, вы не можете просто так взять листик на фото и дать ветру унести его;
   - С фото сложнее выдержать единый стиль, освещение, баланс белого, четкость и т.п. на протяжении игры и жизни проекта;
   - Найти художника для фото сложнее, т.к. это не мейнстрим. И точно так же, сложно найти замену художнику, если он уйдет из проекта по каким-либо причинам;
   - Имея базовые рисованные "кубики", вы можете сделать сколь угодно много контента (уровней) из них. С фото - для каждого расширения вам понадобится новое фото/видео.

В общем случае, видео с бытовой камеры/телефона, это пачка размазанных motion blur-ом кадров. Сделать из них что-то профессионально-выглядещее на экране высокого разрешения (fullHD, к примеру) весьма затруднительно.

2. Возможно практически все на практически любом движке. Хоть на голом OpenGL/WebGL. Уверен что и таких игр, как вы описали несколько штук уже создано. Тут все зависит от вашего авторского видения, как только оно станет более конкретным, тогда можно будет дать более четкий ответ.

---

Есть примеры игр на пересечении этих двух "крайностей", где мир собирается из отдельных рисованных/сканированных/фотографированных деталей.
Так же, можете посмотреть в сторону AR (Augmented Reality), когда игра происходит поверх "настоящего" мира в реальном времени.